# Codeship: Deploying to EC2 Container Service from Docker Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, continuous-deployment, aws-cli, amazon-ecs

I have a project which used Codeship Pro and i have successfully push to Docker Hub, and after that i want to push my project to AWS EC2 Container Service with it.

I followed this documentation:

https://documentation.codeship.com/pro/continuous-deployment/aws/

```
- service: awsdeployment
  command: aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file:///deploy/tasks/backend.json
- service: awsdeployment
  command: aws ecs update-service --service my-backend-service --task-definition backend
```

The problem is in documentation, it doesn't explain what deploy/tasks/backend.json contain,
i tried to remove it in codeship-steps.yml

```
- service: awsdeployment
  command: aws ecs update-service --service my-backend-service --task-definition backend
```

But the result is: An error occurred (ClientException) when calling the UpdateService operation: TaskDefinition not found.

Currently, i use

```
ecs-cli compose up
```

it push my project to my EC2 Container Service using my docker-compose.yml

I spend a long day to figure it out, but still i have no idea to successfully push to my AWS ECS, i can't use ecs-cli command when pushing with shipcode.
What should i do ?

Comment: The `aws ecs` command is calling the AWS CLI (which is preinstalled in the image you are using for deploying to AWS). The required options are explained in more detail on the AWS CLI documentation, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/update-service.html for the `update-service` command for ECS.

Comment: can we use ecs cli commands like i used: 'ecs-cli compose up' on codeship services ?

Comment: Not via the container that we provide, as it only has the AWS CLI installed but the AWS ECS CLI. You can however build a Docker image with the ECS CLI installed (or search for it on Docker Hub) and then use that image to run your commands.

Comment: alright, how about push via aws registry (ECR)? it seems more simpler than use AWS-CLI. I have tried that one, but in the end, it said wrong username even though i have include the auth in my dockercfg file. Is it possible to use this method?

source: https://blog.codeship.com/aws-registry/

Comment: Sure, you can use our generic tutorial on pushing to a remote registry for this, see https://documentation.codeship.com/pro/builds-and-configuration/image-registries/#pushing-images-to-registries in combination with the dockercfg generator for AWS ECR, https://github.com/codeship-library/aws-utilities/blob/master/dockercfg-generator/README.md